# Subclassing in Javascript / OOJS

Tags: javascript, prototype, class-design

I've got a class "A" that has multiple instances. I've got a class "B" that has multiple instances per instance of class "A". The class "B" doesn't need special methods depending on the instance of its parent, but it does need to be able to trigger methods that effect specifically its parent instance. How do I structure this relationship?

To be clear, I'm not describing "Animal --> Human" (a subset). I'm describing "Human --> Tools", whereby the parent has many instances of something, and those instances should have access to methods that affect only their possessive parent instance.

Comment: Can you give a better example? The term *parent* and *sublcasses* are misleading here. This is not scenario where one would apply *inheritance*. This is a *composition* problem. So what exactly do you want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var TypeA = function() { };
TypeA.prototype.doSomething = function() {/*...*/};

var TypeB = function(parent) { this._parent = parent; }
TypeB.prototype.doSomethingToParent = function() { this._parent.doSomething(); }
```

When you instantiate B, always pass in your current A.

If I understand your question correctly?

Comment: Any reason for the underscore?

Comment: A convention I use to hint that the variable is "private" in some sense. No other reason beyond that.